# Change data before submitting the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, forms, greasemonkey

I want to be able to encrypt text in a textbox before submiting a form in facebook.I tried ajaxFORM plugin with beforeSerialize or with beforeSubmit but the encryption doesnt happen.In the code that follows the encrypt function is replaced with alert for debugging purposes.The alert comes right after i run the script and not when i press the submit button on facebook.Also when i press the submit button it asks to refresh the page  and i dont want this.

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.setAttribute('src', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js');
document.body.appendChild(s);


var f = document.createElement('script');
f.setAttribute('src', 'http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js');
document.body.appendChild(f);

var c = document.createElement('script');
c.setAttribute('src', 'http://malsup.github.com/chili-1.7.pack.js');
document.body.appendChild(c);



s.onload=function(){


$(document).ready(function() { 
    // bind form using ajaxForm 
    $(document.activeElement).closest("form").ajaxForm( { 
    beforeSerialize:         alert($(document.activeElement).val()) } ); 
});


};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can control what happens before submitting by calling a click event on the submit button:

```
$("#submit_button").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    alert("Encrypting...");
});
```

You can also drop the `event.preventDefault();` if you want the button to act like it normally would after it has processed your click event. If you want to trigger the submit event yourself, I'd suggest using  `event.preventDefault();`

*Note:*

*I know there is a difference in the order of executing different events (click, change, etc); e.g. a change and click event on the same checkbox results in (click, then change) in Firefox, or (change, then click) in Chrome. If the same is true for the click and submit events on the button, I'd suggest using `preventDefault` so you can trigger the submit yourself when the form is ready to be submitted. This way, it will work in any browser*

Comment: I don't know the id or the name of the submit button so i cant use $(#submit_button).Also in facebook only the first textbox has a submit button.All the other textboxes are submitted by hitting "enter".Thank you for your help.

Comment: so is there a way i can bypass the above problems?

Comment: If they are submitted by enter, there is still a 'submit'-handler attached to it, just not to a button :) Therefore, .submit() will still trigger the event. (Keep in mind, you will need to trigger it like $("#id_of_form or .class_of_forms").submit(); Also, you can find the button by digging down in the DOM: $("body>div>form>input[type=submit]") (not 100% sure of the syntax, check Google, but that's the basic idea. You can also dig up: $("#id_of_element_inside").parent().parent() for example :-)